# Changing img src value

Tags: jquery, image, src

I want the visitors of my web page to able to change the background of my web page when they click a link. I have few skills in javascript and jquery and am not sure how exactly to achieve this. Do display my background i use the following css:

```
#background {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    z-index: -1;
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

and html -

```
<img src="images/backgrnd.jpg" class="stretch" id="background" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing an image's src attribute in jquery is simple:

```
$('#background').attr('src', 'images/newimage.jpg');
```

Comment: If a reply answers your question, you should mark it as the answer. Thanks for the upvote though :)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
$('#somelink').click(function(){
    $('#background').prop('src', 'images/newbackground.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#background").attr("src", "images/new_background.jpg");
```